# How to configure to connect to IBM Websphere MQ Multi Instance Queue Manager from jboss eap standalone.xml

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6

I have created a IBM Websphere MQ Muliti Instance queue manager and I need to connect to this Queue manager from jboss eap 6.4 to achieve High Availability

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the 'host' and 'port' attributes, you can use the 'connectionNameList' property on the Connection Factory. The syntax is:

```
connectionNameList
mqhost1(1414), mqhost2(1414)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please share the full syntax of it please?

Comment: <config-property name="connectionNameList">
    mqhost1(1414),mqhost2(1414)
</config-property>

Answer (score 1):

Or, in the JBoss EAP server configuration file:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">
                    6
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">
                    100
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/factory/aapd/MQQueueSharingConnectionFactory" enabled=
"true" pool-name="MQQueueSharingConnectionFactory">

                        <config-property name="connectionNameList">
                            10.10.189.74(1414), 10.10.189.75(1414)
                        </config-property>
```

You can also use the `connectionNameList` in an MDBs activation specification.